# Get a std::list::iterator from std::reference_wrapper

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I'm coding a Fibonacci heap data structure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) in C++.
This data structure consists of several heaps, with roots connected in a doubly-linked list. Each node has a doubly-linked list of its children. A whole heap has a doubly-linked list of leaf nodes, to support fast pruning. (CLRS 19-3.b)

My implementation of `Node` is:

```
struct Node {
        using Iterator = std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>::iterator;
        using LeafIterator = std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<Node>>>::iterator;
        Iterator parent;
        std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>> child_list;
        T key;
        bool mark = false;
        bool is_leaf = false;
        LeafIterator leaf_iterator;
        Node(const T& key) : key {key} {}
    };
```

My implementation of `FibonacciHeap` is:

```
    using Iterator = std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>::iterator;
    using LeafIterator = std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<Node>>>::iterator;

    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>> NIL;
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>> root_list;
    std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<Node>>> leaf_list;
    Iterator min_element;
```

I used `std::list<std::reference_wrapper<std::unique_ptr<Node>>>` for `leaf_list`, instead of `std::list<Node*>`, because the memory of leaf nodes are solely owned by their parents, and I don't want double-delete crash.

The problem arises when I attempt to delete a leaf node. I can access a leaf node to delete by `leaf_list.begin()`, but I cannot erase it from its parent's `child_list`.

There are two possible workarounds I thought:

- Perform a linear scan from `parent`'s `child_list` to get a `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>::iterator` that matches the given leaf. This is a linear scan, so slow.
- Ditch `leaf_list` and maintain two pointers as member variables of `Node` that contains `prev_leaf` and `next_leaf` to emulate doubly linked list. I don't like this because it would make `Node`s more bloaty.
- ...can't think else for now

What would be the best way to get `std::list<std::unique_ptr<Node>>::iterator` from `std::reference_wrapper` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `std::list<Node*>` would not cause any double deletes, as long as you don't manually delete nodes, and let the actual `unique_ptr` pointers in `child_list` members handle that. You would just need to be careful to avoid using a dangling pointer after a `Node` has been destroyed. But this way still doesn't give a good way to quickly remove a `Node*` from the appropriate `child_list`.

Instead, you could maybe use `std::list<Iterator> leaf_list;`. This is relatively safe since inserts and erases on a `std::list` do not invalidate any iterators (except of course iterators to erased elements).

Though since you still have an invariant to follow, that the iterators in `leaf_list` belong to the appropriate `child_list`, it would be good to help code follow it. Depending on the intended usage and generality of the class, that might mean just putting notes in comments within or just before the `struct Node` definition. Or it might mean making `Node` a proper class with `private` members and a safer `public` interface - I might consider creating custom iterators using `boost::iterator_adaptor` to allow iteration over the leaf nodes without as much danger of breaking the invariant. If you don't expect much reuse, but then find it would be useful again in more contexts or projects, you could of course change these sorts of decisions later (unless too much code gets written using the raw way).

Comment: Good, I switched into ```std::list<Iterator> leaf_list```, and it works nicely!